# Distance calculation for nonlinear features

Tags: feature-selection, feature-engineering

[image]

Dear Data science community,

Please see the attached. I plotted my data using t-SNE. In the figure, group A and B are 100% separable with random forest model. I want to calculate the distance of features in feature space. Do you know any good distance calcuation method for nonlinear data?

Comment: weighted euclidean distance perhaps, else an intrinsic metric derived directly from the features and their domain

Comment: possibly [a metric derived from Information Geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information_metric) can be of help or inspiration